# PHP Scraper With WAMP - Read/write permissions?

Tags: php

I made myself a web scraper a couple of months ago,I Launched it using WAMP it worked well, it would write the results to a CSV file - I have since had a new PC, and as a result a fresh install of WAMP - When I try to run my scraper now it says that it has been completed successfully - "X-amount of data retrived" etc as it always did, Yet there is no file saved - I *think* it may be some setting in php.ini with WAMP perhaps but I am unsure, I have been staring at my screen trying different things, and googling for answers all day to no avail. Any fixes would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code (The section which creates a new file, or writes to an existing one if available)

```
 if(!empty($articles)){
//Create the CSV file
$file = fopen("csv/".$phrase."_".$startPage."-".($startPage + $maxPages - 1).".csv","w"); //open file and truncate, create if it doesn't exist
foreach($articles as $item) {
    fputcsv($file, explode('::',$item));
}
fclose($file);//close the file

echo "<style type=\"text/css\">h1, h2 {font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:lighter;}</style>
    <h1>New file saved</h1>
    <h2>URL Scraped: <a href=\"". $page ."\"><em>". $page ."</em></a></h2>
    <h2>Time Taken: <strong>". ($timeFinish - $timeStart) ." seconds</strong></h2>
    <h2>Total Pages scraped: <strong>". $totalPages ."</strong></h2>
    <h2>Total contacts found: <strong>". count($articles) ."</strong></h2>";
}else{  // end if !empty $html
echo "No content found or bad URL";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: What are the permissions of the `csv` directory?